# Org chart web part for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, organization-chart

I am a beginner at O365 Sharepoint Online and I have to add an organization chart representing the organizational hierarchy of the members of the society but I cannot find a solution for this. Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online does not have a out of the box org chart web part. You can check the organization chart when you click on the user name in a person and group field. It is from the Delve and you can [go here for more information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-office-delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca).

Also there is a [org chart tab in MS teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-organization-tab-in-teams-ff02568b-290a-46d6-ae7a-cda22f723894) which shall be integrated with your SharePoint Online site.

There are also 3rd party web org chart webs which you can turn to.